# Is it possible to use the old ABI of proxy contracts to query the balance of proxy contract historically?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, abi

I am trying to build a web application to query the balance of a wallet address in the pool.
However, the problem is that the ABI of a proxy contract changes all the time but I would still like the get the balance with a web3 query.

Assuming a proxy contract has two versions of logic contracts, v1 and v2
At the point when it switches from v1 to v2
Can I still use v1 ABI to query?

**Or rather what are the requirement to get the balance of a proxy contract historically?**

Comment: I would think that you could always use the same Proxy contract ABI no matter how many times you change logic contracts But I never tested it. Did you find out the answer?